# Updating object using super().update()

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an object, whose attributes I would like to update. Right now, I am able to update a single attribute eg: name. But the object has several attributes which include name, contact_name, contact_email and contact_phone_number.The following is what I have at the moment.

In views.py

```
class MerchantViewSet(GetPrefixedIDMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """POST support for /merchants/."""
    print ("in MerchantViewSet")
    queryset = models.Merchant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CreateMerchantSerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
    # lookup_value_regex = f"{models.Merchant.id_prefix}_[a-f0-9]{32}"
    lookup_value_regex = ".*"
    permission_classes = [permissions.MerchantPermission]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filter the queryset based on the full merchant name or starting with a letter."""
        queryset = models.Merchant.objects.all()
        search_param = self.request.query_params.get("search", None)
        if search_param:
            if search_param.startswith("^"):
                queryset = queryset.filter(name__istartswith=search_param[1:])
            else:
                queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_param)
        return queryset

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data["user"] = request.user.id
        print (self.get_object().name)
        print (request.data)

        merchant = self.get_object()
        print (response)
        print (merchant.name)
        for merchants in models.Merchant.objects.all():
            print (merchants.id)
            if (merchants.id == merchant.id):
                merchants.name = request.data["name"]
                merchants.save()
```

I've tried using

```
response = super(MerchantViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

from what I read in the DRF documentations but using this just returns error 404 when I run my test. Do I simply have to do with I did with name in my code above, with the other attributes? Or is there a more streamlined way to do this?

This is my test:

```
class MerchantsViewSetTest(tests.BigETestCase):  # noqa

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  # noqa

        super(MerchantsViewSetTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.application = tests.get_application()
        tests.create_group("merchant")
        cls.consumer_user = tests.create_consumer()
        cls.admin = tests.create_administrator()

        cls.merchant_geraldine = models.Merchant.objects.create(
            name="Test Account 1",
            contact_name="Geraldine Groves",
            contact_email="geraldine@example.com",
            contact_phone_number="+35310000000",
        )

        cls. merchant_barbara = models.Merchant.objects.create(
            name="Account 2",
            contact_name="Barbara",
            contact_email="barbara@example.com",
            contact_phone_number="+35310000432",
        )


        def test_edit_merchant(self): # noqa

            url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-detail", kwargs={'id': self.merchant_geraldine.prefixed_id})
        # payload
            data = {"name": "Edited"}

        # Put data 
            resp_data = self.put(url, data, user=self.admin, status_code=200)

        # Check if data was updated
            url = reverse("bige_transactions:merchant-list")
        # Try without authenticated user
            self.get(url, status_code=401)
        # Try with authenticated admin user
            resp_data = self.get(url, user=self.admin, status_code=200)
            print (resp_data)
```

Comment: Why do you override `update(..)` in the first place? Django's update will do that.

Comment: So I don't need `update()` at all? I tried without it, I get error 400 when I run my test.

Comment: a 400 usually means that the problem is at the client side (something like an invalid request, etc.). You thus make bad requests.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the request, you can see the request in my test. It's an answer from a previous question. I am able to save by overriding the `update()` method.